# My site is getting http flooded. Is there a solution?

Tags: http, ddos

I've tried everything I could find. Nothing helps. The attackers are flooding my site over the domain name with GET request for links, which do not exist and overload my server. I tried everything I can think of, but obviously I'm missing something crucial.

I am running nginx as a web server on ubuntu.

Any help would mean the world to me. Site is written in laravel.

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Look into universal firewall and fail2ban and you can  setup some throttling jails to ban IPs who are pinging your site at a careless rate.

Comment: you can use cloudflare, you will the rate limiting feature or the "I AM under attack" mode